# update state without causing rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello i am very new to react and started with react hooks. I have some understanding of useState and useEffect hooks but not in depth. I am trying to use the [material table][1] and filter feature to toggle change in filter status. I have code in place which allows me to toggle defaultFilter value. However toggling the defaultFilter reloads the data in table including if i have filtered on other values.

My end goal would be that end users would filter on certain values and then use the toggle button to show active/history rows. Maybe the way i am using useState is causing a rerender instead of just updating the value for the filter or maybe i am way off. I have tried some different approaches but all are causing the state to be refreshed.

Any help would be appreciate it.

```
function handleFiltert() {
        if(filter == "Active") {
            setFilter(null); setButtontext("Hide Historical Data") }
        else {setFilter('Active'); setButtontext("Show Historical Data")}
        //console.log(buttontext)
    }

      const [filter, setFilter] = useState("Active")
      const [buttontext, setButtontext] = useState("Show Historical Data")  `

 <button type="button" onClick={handleFiltert}>
                {buttontext}
            </button>
           <MaterialTable

        columns={[
            { title: "Row Status", field: "ROWSTS", readonly: "true", defaultFilter: filter, defaultSort: "asc"},
            { title: "Programcd", field: "Programcd", readonly: "true"},
            { title: "Program Type", field: "programty", readonly: "true"  },

          ]}
          data={rows}
/>


  [1]: https://material-table.com/#/
```

Comment: If you don't want to rerender why not just store the value in a normal variable?

Comment: i didnt think about that and tried it. However i am not able to update the values in the Material Table when using just normal variable. I can see the value getting updating in console log but not reflecting in UI

Comment: If you want the UI to update, you need a re-render. That's what a re-render is.

Comment: Maybe I’m just confused about what you’re trying to do. If you the values to update wouldn’t you want to rerender?

Comment: Basically my scenario is that i will have many records and some of those will have the status of history and one row which will be have the status of active. The idea is to show the active row first and then if the end user would like, show the history info as well with the active row. so i thought about using the default filter option. The end user would filter on values to get to the active row and then toggle defaultfilter to see the history records as well. however with the toggle, the ui rerenders and the filter values the end user entered are gone.